# Spring Batch skip policy not being called

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a situation where the first steps my job count the number of rows both in source and target databases, so I can present a live progress monitor during the job execution (which can take some days).

Due to a particularity of my inputs, the list of tables that feed the job may not correspond to the list of tables in fact present on both databases (my input can have tables that doesn't exist in the databases). Since most of the list should match the tables present in the databases, I thought using a fault tolerant step for dealing with this.

The pieces of my code that I believe are the most important in the context of this question follow:

**(Step creation)**

```
@Bean( "partitionedSourceRowsCounterStep" )
public Step partitionedSourceRowsCounterStep( @Qualifier( "sourceRowCounterStep" ) Step rowCounterStep, 
                                          @Qualifier( "parallelTasksExecutor" ) TaskExecutor taskExecutor ) {

return stepBuilderFactory
            .get( "partitionedSourceRowsCounterStep" )
            .partitioner( "sourceRowCounterStep", new RowsCounterPartitioner( 
this.model.getEntityNames() ) )
            .step( rowCounterStep )
            .taskExecutor( taskExecutor )
            .build();
}

@Bean( "sourceRowCounterStep" )
public Step rowCounterStep( SourceRowsCounterReader reader, 
                        SourceRowsCounterInMemoryWriter writer,  
                        @Qualifier( "parallelTasksExecutor" ) TaskExecutor taskExecutor ) {

return stepBuilderFactory
            .get( "sourceRowCounterStep" )
            .<Map<String, Object>, Map<String, Object>>chunk( this.config.getChunkSize() )
            .reader( reader )
            .writer( writer )
            .faultTolerant()
            .skipPolicy( new SkipPolicy() {
                
                @Override
                public boolean shouldSkip( Throwable t, int skipCount ) throws SkipLimitExceededException {
                    System.out.println( "SKIP_POLICY WAS CALLED" );
                    return false;
                }
                
            } )
            .taskExecutor( taskExecutor )
            .throttleLimit( 1 )
            .build();
}
```

**(Rows counter reader)**

```
@StepScope
@Slf4j
@Component
public class SourceRowsCounterReader extends AbstractCursorItemReader<Map<String, Object>> {


@Override
protected void openCursor( Connection con ) {
    try {
        String sql = getSql();
        
        log.debug( "Query string: '" + sql + "'" );
        
        if( isUseSharedExtendedConnection() ) {
            preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement( sql, ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY, ResultSet.HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT );
        } else {
            preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement( sql, ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY );
        }
        
        applyStatementSettings( preparedStatement );
        if( this.preparedStatementSetter != null ) {
            preparedStatementSetter.setValues( preparedStatement );
        }
        
        this.rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery(); // Exception happens here!
        
        handleWarnings( preparedStatement );
    } catch( SQLException se ) {
        close();
        throw getExceptionTranslator().translate("Executing query", getSql(), se);
    }

}

@Override
protected SQLExceptionTranslator getExceptionTranslator() {
    return this.customExceptionTranslator;
}

}
```

However, when the code runs I get the error:

```
org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: Failed to initialize the reader
at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:153) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ebb633d0.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:124) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at com.company.steps.SourceRowsCounterReader$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2dbb98e7.open(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemStream.open(CompositeItemStream.java:103) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkMonitor.open(ChunkMonitor.java:114) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemStream.open(CompositeItemStream.java:103) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.open(TaskletStep.java:311) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:205) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler$1.call(TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:138) [spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler$1.call(TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:135) [spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_231]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_231]
Caused by: com.company.steps.jdbc.exception.TableOrViewDoesnExistException: Table doesn't exist; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

at com.company.steps.jdbc.oracle.OracleExceptionTranslator.translate(OracleExceptionTranslator.java:18) ~[classes/:na]
at com.company.steps.SourceRowsCounterReader.openCursor(SourceRowsCounterReader.java:99) ~[classes/:na]
at org.springframework.batch.item.database.AbstractCursorItemReader.doOpen(AbstractCursorItemReader.java:428) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:150) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Besides, no "SKIP_POLICY WAS CALLED" is printed in the terminal, even I have a dozen failures due to the previous exception.

According to the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/step.html#configuringSkip) exceptions should be handled regardless the point of the step chain they are thrown.

Does anyone can see any misconfiguration here?

Spring Boot v2.3.4.RELEASE
Spring Batch v4.2.4.RELEASE

Answer (score 0):

According to your stacktrace, the exception happens while initializing the reader (`SourceRowsCounterReader.openCursor`), meaning that the step did not start yet at this point.

The skip policy will be called once the step starts correclty (ie the reader/writer are correctly initialized).